# Compare variable to multiple strings python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Looking to see if this is the most pythonic way to compare a string variable passed in as an argument in python3. My testing shows that this works, however I was confused to why `or` would not work and `and` will. This is just a demo, the tag variable is set from the command line. When I test with `centos6, centos7, centos8` I hit the `else` and it works as expected.  Is this the best way to do this? Or is this wrong?

```
tag = 'centos6'


if tag != 'centos6' and tag != 'centos7' \
        and tag != 'centos8':
    print('[--os %s] must be [--os centos6] or '
          '[--os centos7] or [--os centos8]' % tag)
    print('fail')
else:
    print('good')
```

Comment: Maybe `if tag not in ['centos6','centos7','centos8']:` or better yet, define a name like: `allowed_os = ['centos6','centos7','centos8']` then `if tag not in allowed_os:`

Comment: What of using `print_this="good" if tag in ['centos6','centos7','centos8'] else "[--os {}] must be [--os centos6] or [--os centos7] or [--os centos8]\nfail".format(tag)` then `print` the variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `or` makes the `if` `True` if the `tag` is not equal to one of the `centos` values, it doesn't matter if it's just one or all of them, `and` makes the `if` `True` only if it's different to all values. Now this is simpler to write:

```py
options = ['centos6', 'centos7', 'centos8']
tag = 'centos6'

if tag not in options:
    ...
```